# Сетевой адаптер теряет сеть

Tags: windows, windows-10, ethernet

Столкнулся с проблемой - после выхода из спящего режима/перезагрузки сетевой адаптер Ethernet не видит сеть (подключён по проводу). Видит её как неопределённую и не имеет подключения к интернету. После отключения и включения адаптера подключение восстанавливается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После поломки встроенного в материнку адаптера поставил PCIe плату, но проблема осталась.
В событиях никаких ошибок не нашёл (может не там искал).
ОC: `windows 10`.
Плата: `dlink dge 560t`.

Comment: с другим роутером ппопробуйте

Comment: На другом компьютере подключённом к этому же роутеру таким же способом нет такой проблемы. Однако если будет возможность попробую.

Comment: В первую очередь проверьте меняется ли статистика полученных Ethernet-пакетов. Скорее всего не получает адрес. Вероятно, проблема - на уровне драйвера.

Comment: @Daemon-5 пробовал различные драйверы, но результата нет.

Comment: Как это просто не прозвучало бы, проверьте кабель, особенно в местах соединений.

Comment: @Daemon-5 Компьютер подключён к роутеру с помощью tp link powerline. Возможно из-за этого? Кабель не отходит.

Comment: если у Вас ещё и промежуточное устройство (это не важно что по силовой линии), то может таки проверить напрямую кабель? Либо на ту же физическую линию посадить другое Ethernet устройство, чтобы проверить линию (и желательно не одно).